# Connect to custom bitcoin node with bitcoinJ

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, bitcoinj

I have full bitcoin testnet core on my server and I am accessing it over dyndns address. I am creating Android bitcoin wallet bitcoinJ and now I am stuck with connecting to my server and using it for making transactions. Is there a way to use bitcoinJ with custom tesnet server or I am at wrong path. Can't find any example online, they are all using `TestNet3Params.get()`.